# Weighing up javascript performance improvements against file size increases

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

#### Background

I've spent some time today optimising a jQuery plugin I made using Chrome DevTools' CPU profiler and managed to achieve a 39.45% reduction in CPU time for the plugin's initialisation code. In this instance, it's a simple plugin which went from 13.41ms down to 8.12ms.

This was achieved through some simple changes to minimise the use of expensive jQuery API calls which I found less-expensive alternatives to, such as using `$(htmlOptionItem).prop('selected')` instead of `$(htmlOptionItem).is(':selected')`.

In making my changes, I've noticed a slight increase in the plugin's uncompressed file size - it's gone from 3.9kB to 4.5kB, which, whilst still very small, got me wondering about where the line should be drawn in **performance optimisation vs resource download overheads**.

#### Question

*Please note that whilst my example is referring to a simple jQuery plugin, my query really is a broader javascript one, not jQuery specific.*

I'm no performance expert, but I recognise that javascript is single-threaded and so writing performant code is important to prevent blocking.

Is such a minute CPU time saving justifiable for the file size increase that comes with it and how do you establish that it is or isn't?

Comment: It might be hard to come up here with more than opinions

Comment: An interesting point, however if you make adequate use of browser caching performance optimisation should still win out.

Comment: My opinion on the matter is that is as long as you get higher percent wise execution speed vs file size your iteration on optimizing your code is a success. Your example is just like that you 39.45% faster initialisation for 15.38% increase in file size. We could safely assume increase in file size directly increases the initialisation speed due to download time(although this might not be correct at all) therefore we can state in your case we have 24.07% optimization. As i said in my opinion this is one way to approach it.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirDrenovski, but that argument falls down if you have a large javascript file with low CPU time - as the CPU time decreases, the time saving would be low, but if the file size increases, it could be quite a large increase, thus comparing the percentages doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: I do agree with you, comparing the percentages dose not feel right to me too, i feel like i'm missing something on my way to answering the main question here "Is it worth it?" exchanging CPU times for size.